# JPA query on @MappedSuperClass. Fetch details of all the child class?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am  having 3 radio buttons **1.Car**, **2.Bike**, **3.Both**. So if i select
 car it will fetch all the car details if i select 2 it will only
 fetch the car details till here i am able to achieve but how to
 fetch both the Car and bike details if I select 3rd radio button
 "both". In below example i want to do the same on selecting **"both"** 
        it will fetch all the documents. What is the best solution for this?

```
    Parent class:
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseProsecutionDocument {

    private long dmsDocumentId;
    private long documentVersion;
    private String fileName;
    …
    }

    Pros class:

    @Entity
    @Table(schema = “reference”, name = “prosecution_documents”)
    public class ProsDocument extends BaseProsecutionDocument {

    private Long id;
    private Long prosId;
    private Long ocportalSubmissionId;
    …
    }

    Sumisiion class:

    @Entity
    @Immutable
    @Table(schema = “reference”, name = “submission_docs”)
    public class submissionDocument extends BaseProsecutionDocument {

    private Long id;
    private Long inventionId;
    …
    }
    I want to know how to write the query for that..like
    i have written for those 2 radio buttons:

    public interface ProsecutionDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository {
    @Query(value = “SELECT ppd FROM ProsDocument ppd ” +
    “WHERE ppd.submissionId IN (SELECT p.id FROM submission p WHERE 
UPPER(p.doc) = UPPER(:doc)) ” +
    “AND ppd.documentType.documentType in (‘OFFICE’)”)
    Page findSubmissionOfficeDocumentsByDoc(@Param(“doc”) String docket, 
Pageable pageable);
    }
```

> Or do I need to change the @MappedSuperClass to @Entity and use 
>     @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Create a Base Class with the basic fields

   ```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public class FooBase {

   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   }
   ```
2. Map this class to your table on empty class

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "foo")
   public class Foo  extends FooBase{

   }
   ```
3. Map nested object, collections, subresources on another class but same table "foo"

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "foo")
   public class FooNested extends FooBase {

       @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
       @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
       private List<Bar> barList;
       }
   ```
4. Create One Reporitory for each Entity
5. Use one or other repository to FETCh or Not the realted tables/entities